# How is it most appropriate to credit a post of the philosophy stack-exchange?

Tags: discussion

How to credit a post of the philosophy stack-exchange?

I ask this question since in a homework essay I submitted I provided in the reference a link to a post of the user @Conifold that I found helpful. But my teacher noted to me after he read my essay that it is not acceptable but to credit only professional academics and published papers. I told my teacher that the user I credited seems to me a professional philosopher and historian and that since I read critically whatever I run into and since I learnt from what he wrote I did not want to not credit his post as one of the sources that I was influenced by while writing my homework. But my teacher insists that I will avoid list any references that are 'non-academic' from now on.

Comment: Just in general I wouldn't try to cite anything on a stack exchange site (stuff like mathoverflow is slightly different) when writing a paper, especially not a site like this that is largely made up of users who are not professional philosophers. Even if you try to read what is posted here critically, it's not the same as reading a primary source text or something peer reviewed. I would listen to your teacher, especially if they asked you to not cite non-academic sources. Instead of citing Conifold's answer, you should cite the things cited *in* the answer.

Comment: I understand wanting to cite an answer that was helpful for you, especially in the spirit of giving credit where credit is due, but when writing an academic essay it's more important to just cite verifiable things. If Conifold says something like "Quine said x, here is a quote from one of his papers" and that answers your question, then you should just quote Quine himself and that essay, not the answer on this site. Again, especially since your teacher specifically asked you not to cite this site. Philosophy.SE isn't an academic stack exchange where academic works of philosophy are produced.

Comment: Not_Here is right. While you are correct to add a reference here if you used a post, it is not considered a very strong one, so you're better off continuing from the answer to find out more about the subject, in academic sources, and referencing those.

Comment: By the way, questions like this are welcome on [academia.se].

Comment: Thank you @Not_Here for your elaborated comments and thank you Keelan for the additional comments. If may further share: rather than cite in my essay Conifold's post, I used the references and the narrative he presented in it. And it was helpful to me and so felt it is right to give him credit in the form of adding link to his post in the online references section of my essay, for wanted to acknowledge his helpfulness somehow. But I understand that it is not allowed or otherwise not acceptable in academic writings. Thank you again for your comments.

Comment: This: `I used the references and the narrative he presented in it.` is slightly troubling. If you use the references, that's fine you don't need to cite. Depending on what's meant by "narrative", you may still need to cite Conifold. / In terms of academic texts, you can *acknowledge* things or people as helpful without a formal cite, but there's absolutely no rule against citing things that are not themselves published books.

Comment: Thank you @virmaior for this comment. I understand the subtle issue - when wrote 'narrative' meant that used part of the historical flow he posted (in my own words) in historical background section of my essay and relied on references he presented. It is my preference to be able to use this site as a source that I may cite or list in my references. As shared, my teacher said to me to rely only on academic sources. But from what you explain I still may acknowledge users and people and sites and things as helpful. Thank you again for your comment.

Comment: The question of whether @Conifold is a professional philosopher or not has been plaguing me for quite a while :-)